# decorator function is not executing

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to print the pattern as follows:

```
******
20
******
```

I used decorator function to print the pattern before and after main function.
But my code is not printing the pattern only main function is getting executed.
Please suggest how I can write the function in a better format.

Following is my code:

```py
def banner(str1, len1):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args1):
            new_line = '\n'
            str2 = str1 * len1
            return f'{str2}{new_line}{func(*args1)}{new_line}{str2}'
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@banner('*', 6)
def func1(a, b):
    print(a*b)

func1(5,4)
```

Comment: Thanks @ddejohn,it is working fine and understood the reason. Since i don't have enough points to close the question so it will still be open.

Comment: You can accept my answer. That will close the question. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return a * b`, not print it:

```py
@banner('*', 6)
def func1(a, b):
    return a * b
```

Output:

```py
>>> func1(5, 4)
'******\n20\n******'

>>> print(func1(5, 4))
******
20
******
```

The reason you need to return is because your wrapped function is called in the middle of that f-string, with `func(*args1)`. With only a `print` statement in the function originally, your function defaulted to the implicit `return None` that all functions in Python default to if a `return` is not explicitly provided.